Wifi card does not work (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
I recently bought an MSI Alpha 17 C7VG-019XES with the following specifications:

Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 7945HX
RAM: 32GB
Storage: 1TB SSD
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 4070
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 (fresh install)

The issue is that the Wi-Fi card “card Wi-Fi Qualcomm WCN785x” doesn't seem to work properly. After installing Ubuntu 24.04, the system doesn't detect any Wi-Fi networks, and there's no option to connect wirelessly. I've tried a few basic troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Steps I've tried so far:

Checked if the Wi-Fi drivers were installed by running lshw -C network, but only the wired network card is listed; there's no sign of the wireless card.
Tried installing additional drivers through "Software & Updates" > Additional Drivers, but no Wi-Fi related options show up.
Updated repositories and the system using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, but the issue persists.
Checked the BIOS to ensure that the Wi-Fi is enabled, and it seems fine.

Additional details:

The Wi-Fi card is the factory-installed one, (card Wi-Fi Qualcomm WCN785x).
I’ve also looked for proprietary drivers but haven’t found a clear solution.

I would greatly appreciate any help to solve this problem. Has anyone experienced a similar issue with this laptop model or chipset, and could you suggest any steps to fix this?
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

You may have to use mainline from github, https://github.com/bkw777/mainline to install a newer kernel as I suspect you will see an error about regdb bin missing in results from terminal for sudo dmesg | grep ath
At this time, I am unable to figure out what upstream kernel commit fixes this

Gracias jeremi31. Aunque he actualizado el kernel del 6.0.8.40 al 6.10 y en ningún caso me fue de utilidad. Puede ser que me haya saltado algún paso. Gracias

Edit your question to include results from terminal for sudo dmesg|grep arh
